# How to get configuration for WCF Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I want to check whether the endpoint is defined in the configuration before I'll try to create it

```
System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<T> sourceClient = new System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<T>(EndpointName, new EndpointAddress(discoveryUri));
```

To check it I need get a configuration but how can I define whether I need to use `WebConfigurationManager` or `ConfigurationManager`. Is there any way to define where a WCF service is hosted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to need to have the information yourself - the WCF service itself doesn't know whether it'll be hosted in IIS or self-hosted. After all, it's just a `ServiceHost` instance being spun up some way.

So I guess you'd have to have some setting that you can put into either `web.config` or `app.config` - something like:

```
<add key="WCFHost" value="IIS" />
```

or

```
<add key="WCFHost" value="CustomApp" />
```

and then evaluate that value and depending on what you get back, either open WebConfigurationManager or just ConfigurationManager.

You might think you could check for the presence of `HttpContext`: if it's NULL, then you're running in a custom app, if it's not NULL, then it's the web scenario. But that doesn't work since you can host a WCF Service in IIS (thus you'd have a `web.config` to consult) but without the ASP.NET compatibility settings, in which case, `HttpContext` would be NULL *even though* you're running inside a web hosting scenario.

One option would be to check this setting here:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
```

This will contain the full path to the current AppDomain's configuration file - if it's a web app, this will contain a path + `web.config` at the end.

So if you check

```
if(Path.GetFileName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile) == "web.config")
```

you can be pretty sure you're in a web app and you have a `web.config` to look at.